# In Silverlight Datagrid, How to add a new row when focus goes away from Last Row?

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I want to add a new row in my Silverlight DataGrid, when user try to go from LastRow to NextRow by Tab/Enter (as it last row, DataGrid loses focus). I can not use RowEditEnded event as it will fire even if i move to a PreviousRow from LastRow.

Can anyone help me achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at DataGrid source code you can see that it traps key down event (f.i. to realize functionality like go to next row on enter pressed). As solution I propose to implement own grid inherited from DataGrid and add event which raised when user presses enter(or other) button. Own control:

```
 public class MyDataGrid : DataGrid
 {
        public event EventHandler OnLastRowEnterPressed;

        protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnKeyDown(e);
                if (ItemsSource != null 
&& ItemsSource.Cast<object>().Count() - 1 == SelectedIndex 
&& e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                RaiseLastRowEnterPressed();
            }
        }

        private void RaiseLastRowEnterPressed()
        {
            if (OnLastRowEnterPressed != null)
                OnLastRowEnterPressed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
 }
```

Using:

```
ObservableCollection<Foo> source = new ObservableCollection<Foo>()
                                  {
                                      new Foo(), new Foo(), new Foo(),
                                  };
myDataGrid.OnLastRowEnterPressed += (s, e) => source.Add(new Foo());
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = source;
```

Comment: well vladimir, there seems to be no simple/direct way to add new row after last row exit. the above solution will work but with consequences of event being raised in other key press events also.

Comment: well as i can not put the whole solution as comments (comment length validation) i have put it as an answer below. on 'pressed key' check, i didn't get the 'Enter' key in my logs when i do use it.

Answer (score 1):

well vladimir, there seems to be no simple/direct way to add new row after last row exit. your solution will work but with consequences of event being raised in other key press events also. i have come up with the combination of events to get the solution.

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnKeyDown(e);
    addFlag = (e.Key == Key.Tab);
}

protected override void OnLostFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    addFlag = (addFlag && true); 
    base.OnLostFocus(e);
}

protected override void OnRowEditEnded(DataGridRowEditEndedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnRowEditEnded(e);
    addFlag = (addFlag && IsLastRowSelected);
    if (addFlag)
        AddItem();
    addFlag = false;
}

protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
{            
    base.OnKeyUp(e);
    addFlag = false;
}

protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
    addFlag = false;
}

private void AddItem()
{
    if (RaiseAddEvent!= null)
    {
        this.Focus();
        RaiseAddEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        this.UpdateLayout();
        this.CurrentColumn = this.Columns[0];
        this.BeginEdit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Routed events concept where trapping the Enter/Tab key , you can add new row to the data grid control.

Answer (score 0):

I will expose by few steps. So lets start now..

1)Declare your event in constructor of this class.

```
this.DataGrid1.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(DataGrid1_KeyDown);
you also can it in XAML file.
...KeyDown="DataGrid1_KeyDown".....
```

2) Go to your keydown event & wrie the code.

```
var focusedElement = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement();
DataGrid detailsDataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
int dataGridrows = detailsDataGrid.ItemsSource.OfType<object>().Count();
if (e.Key == Key.Tab && (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) == ModifierKeys.Shift)
return;
if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
try
{
detailsDataGrid.SelectedIndex = row.GetIndex();
{

itemMaster.TransactionChilds.Add(transactionChild);
detailsDataGrid.SelectedItem = transactionChild;
}
}
```

3) Now code line by line..

```
DataGridRow row = DataGridRow.GetRowContainingElement(focusedElement as FrameworkElement);
DataGridColumn column = DataGridColumn.GetColumnContainingElement(focusedElement as FrameworkElement);
TransactionMaster itemMaster = this.DataFormVoucher.CurrentItem as TransactionMaster;
decimal serialNumber = 0;
if (buttonPress == "Modify")
 if (dataGridrows - 1 == detailsDataGrid.SelectedIndex && column.DisplayIndex == 5)

TransactionChild transactionChild = new TransactionChild()"[None]",DateTime.Now.Date,catch (Exception ex)Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

.DataGridChild.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(DataGridChild_KeyDown);
```

3) Now understand the code line by line

i) first 3 lines are used to take which row of a datagrid is selected.

ii)When new row will add in this case i have used Tab key you can also change this.Another things is if an user predd Tab+Shift then it will go through (default as control focus).

iii) then check is it last row & last column of this grid, if yes then add new row or else.

iv) to add a blank new row just pass your object (EDMX Model Table)